# IF statement in Dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, dropdown, formula, powerapps-canvas

I'm trying to fill the blank label with a phrase when the dropdown is equal to `SI`, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why?

I put `If(Dropdown1.SelectedText="SI";"¿Desde cuándo se está prestando?")`, but Power Apps show me the same error incompatible type for comparison, cannot compare the types, Record, Text.

Which option I have to select "Text"; "OnSelect"; "Fill"? and then write the formula?

[image]

Comment: What is the data source of drop down (`items` property of drop down)?

Comment: Its a excel's list in a sharepoint. No sharepoint list

Comment: Try using below formula in my answer. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: i've already used previously, serveral times, this formula and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Set **Text** property of label control to:

```
If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "SI"; "¿Desde cuándo se está prestando?")
```

**Documentation**:

1. [Drop down control in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-drop-down)
2. [If and Switch functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if)